# How to return object more efficient without copying

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to implement a small C++ helper that reads a given file into a `std::string`.

This is what I have:

```
    std::string ReadFile(const std::string& filePath)
    {
        std::ifstream fileStream(filePath);
        std::string fileContent((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fileStream)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        return fileContent;
    }
```

This piece of code generates a string and then returns a copy of it. I could void the function and take a `std::string&` as second parameter to read the data into. But I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this?!

Comment: Most compiler will use RVO when returning this object, and, if they do not do i, this is a local object, so if you are using C++11 or newer, they will do a move

Comment: Mhh so I don't have to worry about manually moving it?! I am using VS 2017 compiler...

Comment: @DoubleVoid No you don't have to worry about that. It's done well optimized with most modern compilers.

Comment: @DoubleVoid You're late to the party.  Good compilers have been optimized things like this for over a decade now.

Comment: Last time I checked out this all was when C++11 came out. Then went back to C#. Thus my stupid  question here. Thanks! :)